# has_and_belongs_to_many -- query Model1 items given Model2 id list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have Model1 and Model2 which `has_and_belongs_to_many` to each other.
Given a list of id of Model2, how can I query Model1 associated with them?

I have to use a join, but how exactly? If it were one to many one, I'd do this:

```
    select m1.* from model1 as m1
    inner join model2 as m2
    on m1.id = m2.m1_id
    where m2.id in (?)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would accomplish this in Rails with the same query you're building manually, expressed in `ActiveRecord` as

```
Model1.joins('inner join model2').where(model2: { id: list_of_ids })
```

Comment: `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"`

Comment: sql `SELECT  "model1".* FROM "model1" inner join model2 WHERE "model2"."id" IN (1, 2, 3) `